# How to find the coordinates of the intersection of a line and a circle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, analytic-geometry, circles

I'm trying to find the coordinates of the intersection of a line and a circle. Here is my depiction

[image]

Blue line is horizontal, circle centre $(50,50)$, radius $50$.

Can anyone please help me to find the solution?

Comment: Is the blue line horizontal? What is center and radius of the circle?

Comment: You need to first give us information about your sketch. The equations of the circle and the line are needed to find the intersection, otherwise it cannot be done. Information that lead to the equation can include the cartesian coordinates, center-radius of the circle etc.

Comment: yes, blue line is horizontal line, that image was drawn using paint, center and radius values are known approximately circle center is 50, 50 and radius 50. any formula to find intersect coordinates?

Comment: Your diagram is incorrect, if the circle has centre $(50,50)$ then the intersection between the red line and blue line $(100,150)$ should be above the centre, not below it

Comment: @lioness99a I’d guess that these are coordinates in a viewport that uses a left-handed ($y$ increases downward) coordinate system.

Comment: As lioness99a points out in her answer, the line and circle don’t intersect, but you could’ve figured that out pretty quickly by yourself by noting that the maximum $y$-coordinate of the circle—the $y$-coordinate of its center plus its radius—is less than the $y$-coordinate of the horizontal line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a circle with centre $(50,50)$ and radius $50$, so equation of the circle is $$(x-50)^2+(y-50)^2=2500$$

We know the line is a horizontal line starting at the point $(100,150)$, and so it has the equation $$y=150$$

We want to find all possible co-ordinates of intersection, so we substitute $y=150$ into the equation of the circle:

\begin{align}(x-50)^2+(150-50)^2&=2500\\
(x-50)^2+100^2&=2500\\
(x-50)^2+10000&=2500\\
(x-50)^2&=-7500\\
x-50&=\pm\sqrt{-7500}\\
x&=50\pm\sqrt{-7500}\end{align}

As this is an imaginary number, the line and the circle do not intersect.

Answer (score 1):

To find the coordinates of the points that are intersection of the curve
$$
f(x,y)=0\qquad\qquad(\star)
$$
and the line 
$$
y=mx-b\qquad\qquad(\star\star)
$$
just plug in the $y$ from $(\star\star)$ into $(\star)$, i.e. solve the equation
$$
f(x,mx+b)=0\qquad\qquad(\star\star\star)
$$
for $x$. When the curve is a circle, or just any conic, the latter equation $(\star\star\star)$ is actually an equation of degree $2$ whose solution are easily computable from the very well known quadratic formula. The solutions of $(\star\star\star)$ are the $x$-coordinates of the intersection points. Now you can plug in these values back into $(\star\star)$ to get the $y$-coordinates.